# Large CSV file upload using JQuery/Ajax in php?

Tags: php, jquery, csv, file-upload, large-data

I want to upload a very large csv file into database,i.e, the size of the csv file will be more than 1 GB. I want to upload all data from csv file to mysql table as quick as possible. Please suggest me tha is it possible or not?

And i want to use JQuery/Ajax for doing this job?

Comment: Do you want to use your own script, or a management tool like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I want to use my own script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webservers have a max-execution time and a max-upload-size in php.ini. You probably need to edit these settings. I would recommend to use a chunked upload function.

Here is a nice upload lib that supports chunked upload with jQuery + PHP it's called: [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

Comment: Thanks to answers my question